# Console - created new project; auto-created app engine app; can't set billing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am getting very confused with the whole cloud console api console thing.

I just created a new Cloud Console project in order to setup some GCE instances. It seems to have auto-created an App Engine app. That is fine, but when I go to enable billing, it tells me that it cannot enable billing for app engine apps and that I need to do that in App Engine Console.

Earlier this week, I tried to setup a project to include both an existing App Engine app and Compute Engine. I was asked to got through the request access process like before GCE was available.

I created a project in the Cloud Console by starting in the App Engine console and choosing Cloud Integration. I said there was an error creating the project, but it seems like it created it. However, when I go to that project in Cloud Console, there is no option to even add Compute Engine.

Two questions:
(1) Is there something outlining the differences between Cloud Console and API Console and when it is most appropriate to use one over the other?
(2) How do I get a project (in either one I suppose) that includes an existing App Engine app and Compute Engine resources that I want to create in this project?

Thanks for your help.

-- Jay

Comment: As a follow up ... and shorter ...
How do I take an existing App Engine app and add Compute Engine?

Answer (score 1):

1. Cloud Console is essentially a planned replacement for the API console,
   however it may not have all functionality yet
2. Try going to appengine admin console application settings, and at the bottom of
   the page cloud integration. Click on create project. Once it succeeds go to the cloud
   console and enable billing for Compute Engine

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried the steps you mention to get an existing app engine project into a cloud console project in order to then enable billing (or turn on) GCE. However, I get an error when I do this. I think I get the error because I have done it before :)
In othere words, some time in the past, I have done this so there is an exiting cloud console project with this app engine project in it. However, there is no way to add GCE from there.